# How To Authenticate To IBM Message Hub Without Jass Login Module

Tags: apache-kafka, ibm-cloud, message-hub

I have tried setting up a connection to kafka-message-hub on Bluemix using a Liberty for Java app. I followed the docs and the git repository example. It creates/uses a `jaas.conf` file fine and says it logs in. When a message is written, however, it says "Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms." In order to write a message, I had to add the following code to the `server.xml` file:

```
    <jaasLoginModule id="KafkaClient"
            className="org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule"
            controlFlag="REQUIRED" libraryRef="kafkaLoginLib">

    <options serviceName="kafka" username="MYUSERNAME" password="MYPASSWORD" />
</jaasLoginModule>
```

However, the docs say (under "How to migrate the Kafka client from 0.9.x to 0.10.x"):

1. Delete the Message Hub login Jar module.
2. Change your `jaas.conf` file to the following code:

`KafkaClient {
      org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
      serviceName="kafka"
        username="<your username>"
        password="<your password>";
    };`

3. Add the following line to your consumer and producer properties:
    `sasl.mechanism=PLAIN`

Am I missing something here? It seems like the instructions say I don't need this module anymore, but I can't get it to work without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the docs are correct, though when using Liberty you define a  in server.xml rather than a jaas.comf file.

please take a look at our updated Liberty sample using the 0.10.x client

https://github.com/ibm-messaging/message-hub-samples/tree/master/kafka-java-liberty-sample

that sample does no longer include the deprecated messagehub login.jar

Comment: I see, so the actual jar is not needed, but the serverxml is needed. Is the jaas.conf needed?  I don't quite understand why it seems like I need my credentials in server.xml and jaas.conf.

Comment: I figured out my issue, I read code from java-console-sample, and then also read some code from java-kafka-sample so I got authentication mixed up.  Thanks!